# Select records where all rows have same value in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my sample table

```
Col1   Col2
 A      1
 B      1
 A      1
 B      2
 C      3
```

I want to be able to select distinct records where all rows have the same value in Col1 and Col2. So my answer should be

```
Col1   Col2
 A      1
 C      3
```

I tried

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

This gives me

```
Col1   Col2
 A       1
 B       1
 B       2
 C       3
```

which is not the result I am looking for. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Are you just looking to grab rows where Col1 = A have Col2 = 1?

Comment: @eteich - No. I have edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col2) aCol2 FROM t
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1
```

Output:

```
| COL1 | ACOL2 |
|------|-------|
|    A |     1 |
|    C |     3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63c72/1).

Basically, this makes sure that amount the different values for `col2` are unique for a given `col1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

For example SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d98c8b/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can try either of the below -

```
select col1, col2 from 
(             
select 'A'    Col1 ,   1 Col2
from dual
union all 
select 'B'      , 1
from dual
union all
select 'A'       ,1
from dual
union all
select 'B'       ,2
from dual
)
group by col1, col2
having count(*) >1;
```

OR

```
select col1, col2
from
( 
    select col1, col2, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2) cnt 
    from 
        (             
        select 'A'    Col1 ,   1 Col2
        from dual
        union all 
        select 'B'      , 1
        from dual
        union all
        select 'A'       ,1
        from dual
        union all
        select 'B'       ,2
        from dual
        )
)
where cnt>1;
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server - this is an Oracle solution (use of dual table)

Comment: I used it for testing purpose since i did not have a table with these values.